# QuickTime Player will not play .mov file

Tags: quicktime, mov

My QuickTime doesnt want to play a .mov file.  I tried to convert `.mov` to `.mp4` format using cloud convert but it gave error message:

```
Converter error: oov atom not found . PCO11_059_RM.mov: Invalid data found when processing input.
```

I've got the latest OS X software, 10.11 El Capitan, which I'm assuming would give me the latest QuickTime Player.  Any clues?

Comment: Has the `mov` file ever been playable? Did you create the movie or download it? Maybe the source will help suggest a suitable application to play it back.

Comment: Select the file in the Finder, then use the menu item **File > Get Info** to see if a **More Info** segment is present. If so, what does it say?

Answer (score 1):

## Try VLC

Try playing the file using [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). VLC tends to be able to play files and formats that do not work in QuickTime Player on the latest OS X.

### Re-encode using VLC or Handbrake

If VLC works, then you can use VLC itself or a tool like [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr) to re-encode the file to a format that works in QuickTime Player.

### Many Formats in One

The `mov` file format is a wrapper and can represent many different media formats internally.

With the Finder, use **Get Info** on the `mov` file. What do you see in the **More Info:** section? As an example, in the screenshot below the movie is really a collection of photos with cross fades.

[image: Get Info on Movie file]

Comment: Thanks Graham.  I downloaded VLC but it doesnt want to play it either.  I dragged the file to the VLC player, it sits in the play list but when you press play it flinches like it wants toplay but then nothing happens.   Its difficult to explain with out a screen shot/gif.  I also can't "get info" on the file because I cant open it.  Once again thanks for your detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

Read at answers from apple discussions:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6601106?start=0&tstart=0

A MOV file is basically and MOV file container containing any form of compatible data. Thus, it is often helpful include information regarding what form of data is actually contained within the file.
Since the original file was recorded on an iPhone, the MOV file should contain H.264 video with AAC audio and should be compatible with both the QT X v10.3 and QT 7 players under Mavericks. However, since the file was obviously edited (at least the filename was changed), can you confirm the type of data actually contained in the?
In some cases, an iPhone (H.264/AAC) video may not open correctly in QT following security and/or system updates. In some cases, simply rebooting the system may "fix" the problem.
Another possible test you can run is to try and play the file in a third-party media player. If the file plays correctly, then the file is okay and the problem is most likely associated with the codec configuration, the player app, the PLIS file, etc. and you will have to run further tests.
In still other cases, a file may become corrupted during editing or transmission.